# How to get mean of a variable through time within a given boundarybox (lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I have this plotted area average of the EDIR variable through time using the code below. However, I'd like to know how I could set minimum and maximum lat/lon like a boundary box so I could plot an area average of the EDIR variable within the set lat/lon box. Thank you!

```html
ld0 = xr.open_mfdataset('path/*LDASOUT*', condcat_dim='time')

t2=ld0.EDIR.mean(dim='x','y'))

t2.plot.line('-',color='black',linewidth=3,label='control_run')

plt.legend()
plt.show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lat` and `lon` are coordinate variables in your dataset, you can use the `sel` method.

```
da = ld0['EDIR'].sel(lon=slice(min_lon, max_lon), lat=slice(min_lat, max_lat))
```

More examples of using xarray's coordinate based selection can be found in the xarray documentation: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#masking-with-where), it seems you can select boundaries in coordinates using `t2.where(t2.x < lon2, drop=True)` for example. I am on my phone so I can not test it right now, but something like :

```
temp = ld0.where( ( (t2.x > lon1)  &  (t2.x < lon2) & (t2.y > lat1)  &  (t2.y < lat2)  ), drop=True)
```

should give you the appropriate mask. You can then calculate and plot the spatial mean of this array.